# Round the edges of photos using jQuery

Tags: jquery, rounded-corners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201112/round-the-edges-of-photos-using-jquery/1201242#1201242)

I would like to round the corners of photos (  tag not background images)

Can jQuery accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270380/jquery-round-corners - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521432/best-jquery-rounded-corners-script - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940191/rounded-corners-on-a-fieldset - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152529/css-how-to-add-rounded-corner-with-border-and-no-images I guess al of: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounded-corners

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a question on SO like this before.

Here's another possible plugin - http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

An example - http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/image.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique which doesn't require jQuery, just CSS.

http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/rounded_images/css-only.php

You could alwyas just round the actual images.  Here's a free website that does the work for you:

http://www.roundpic.com/